# Why is String#chomp named like this

Tags: ruby

Most Ruby methods are named (in my eyes) logically and are sometimes abbreviations of their action. `Numeric#divmod` returns the **div** ision quotient and **mod** ulus, `Numeric#fdiv` stands for **f** loat **div** ision and they both make sense.

What does `chomp` in `String#chomp` mean, or what does it stand for?

Comment: Well, it chomps something. Maybe inspired by perl http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html

Comment: `chomp` is a method from Perl (http://perlmeme.org/howtos/perlfunc/chomp_function.html) that Matz was probably familiar with.  The Ruby "principal of least surprise" is what surprises Matz the least, not all programmers :)

Comment: As you are from switzerland and wondering about the meaning: chomp is "abbeissen" in german.

Comment: God and I always thought it was an abbreviation. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Dirk: Keep in mind that `chomp` was added to Perl because [`chop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chop.html)'s behavior was often confusing and surprising so we have confusion piled on confusion piled on word play, hooray!

Comment: There's also [`String#chop`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-chop) to add to the confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an extension or play on the word "chop" (to cut). It also has a direct meaning:

> **chomp** verb \ˈchämp, ˈchȯmp\
>     : to chew or bite on something

Source:
http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chomp

Ruby docs:

> **chomp**(separator=$/) → new_str
>   Returns a new String with the given record separator removed from the end of str (if present). If $/ has not been changed from the default Ruby record separator, then chomp also removes carriage return characters (that is it will remove \n, \r, and \r\n).

So this method "chomps" or "chews" at the end of the string and removes it.

Hopefully that makes better sense now.